# Imprimir en html respuesta ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

hago la siguiente consulta ajax:

```html
$.ajax({
                    url: '',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: '',
                    success: function(response){ 
                        if (response == 1){
                            nom= [];
                        }
                        else{
                            nom = JSON.parse(response)
                            // console.log('Esto es la respuesta :'+nom)
                            for (var p = 0; p<nom.length; p++){
                                // console.log(nom[p].nombre)
                                text = nom[p].nombre 
                                console.log(text)
                                $('#textoP').html(text)
                            }
                        } 
                    }    
                });
```

Me devuelve dos nombres, que quiero insertar en la tabla temporal como filas y mostrar sus datos. Entonces quiero que me genere la tabla tantas filas como nombres tenga en este caso solo me genera el primer nombre:

```html
 fila2 += '<th id="textoP" style=" font-size: 0.9em;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #dddddd;"></th>'
```

Comment: podes usar mejor `map()` en reemplazo del `for`. te quedaría algo así `nom.map(item => {text = item.nombre})`

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta pulsando en [edit] y coloca lo que pusiste en comentarios en mi respuesta o bien pon cómo tienes el código ahora. En comentarios no se puede apreciar todo el contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en esta línea: `$('#textoP').html(text)` del código. Al usar `html()` reemplazas cada vez el contenido del elemento, como bien dice la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

> When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that
> was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.
> Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event
> handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the
> new content.
>
> ---
>
> Cuando se usa `.html()` para establecer el contenido de un elemento,
> cualquier contenido que estaba en ese elemento es completamente
> reemplazado por el nuevo contenido. Además, jQuery elimina otras
> construcciones, como controladores de datos y eventos, de elementos
> secundarios antes de reemplazar esos elementos con el nuevo contenido.

Considera usar `append()` el cual, como dice la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/append/):

> The `.append()` method inserts the specified content as the last child
> of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the first
> child, use `.prepend()`).
>
> ---
>
> El método `.append()` inserta el contenido especificado como el último
> elemento secundario de cada elemento en la colección jQuery (para
> insertarlo como el primer elemento secundario, use `.prepend()`).

```
                        for (var p = 0; p<nom.length; p++){
                            // console.log(nom[p].nombre)
                            text = nom[p].nombre 
                            console.log(text)
                            $('#textoP').append(text)
                        }
```

#### Optimización

Cuando vayas a modificar algo en el DOM no debes olvidar que **éste se rederiza cada vez que lo modificas**, por eso no conviene nunca modificar el DOM dentro de un bucle. Construye una cadena y haz `append` una sola vez, **fuera del bucle**:

```
                        var text;

                        for (var p = 0; p<nom.length; p++){
                            text += `${nom[p].nombre}<br />`; 
                        }
                        /*
                          El DOM se modificará una sola vez
                          No N veces, donde N puede ser
                          10 veces, 100 veces, 99999 veces
                        */
                        $('#textoP').append(text)
```

En el caso de necesitar modificar varias partes del DOM, conviene que uses [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

Por otra parte, si se trata de crear una celda por cada nombre, debes hacer `append` en un elemento `tr`, no en un elemento `th` y rodear cada valor dentro del bucle por `th`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
var response = '[{"nombre":"PERIODO DE PRUEBA"},{"nombre":"PERIODO EXPERIMENTO"}]';

var nom = JSON.parse(response);

var text;

for (var p = 0; p < nom.length; p++) {
  text += `<th>${nom[p].nombre}</th>`;
}
/*
  El DOM se modificará una sola vez
  No N veces, donde N puede ser
  10 veces, 100 veces, 99999 veces
*/
$('#tableHeaders').append(text)
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tableHeaders">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta Cedano. Me ocurre lo siguiente ahora:  Al meterlo como usted me ha puesto me aparecen los dos con un undefined delante ejemplo: (undefinedPrueba1Prueba2) en la misma fila, me gustaría que fuera en filas distintas gracias.

Comment: @nosoyGuti ¿podrías poner un `console.log(nom);` justo antes del `for` y decirnos qué muestra? Sin saber lo que hay en el objeto no podría decirte a qué se debe ese comportamiento, puede que algún elemento no tenga la clave `nombre`. Por otra parte, viendo que `textoP` es un elemento `th`, explícanos lo que debe ocurrir, si se debe crean un `th` por cada nombre o cómo va el asunto. No es lo mismo meter datos en elementos como `p`, `div` ... que meterlos en filas o celdas de una elemento `table`.

Comment: Este es el resultado;Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { nombre: "PERIODO DE PRUEBA" }
​
1: Object { nombre: "PERIODO EXPERIMENTO" }
​
length: 2 y asi como lo tengo yo   success: function(response){ 
                        
                            nom = JSON.parse(response)
                        
                            var text;
                            console.log(nom)
                            for (var p = 0; p<nom.length; p++){
                                text += `${nom[p].nombre}<th/>`; 
                            } $('#textoP').append(text)}

Comment: @nosoyGuti parece que los objetos vienen a su vez dentro de un array, prueba  a definir  `nom` así:  **`nom = JSON.parse(response)[0];`** y dinos si desaparece el `undefined`. Y, si quieres un `th` por cada nombre, construye cada `text` empezando por `<th>` luego el contenido y luego `</th>`.

Comment: La tabla se crea a través de una funcion  con sus días como encabezado th y luego se muestra cada día dependiendo del mes. Ahora quiero hacer un encabezado de la consulta de ajax con los nombres que me vengan como otro th y que de cada nombre me muestre los días marcados. Que en principio lo coge todo menos los nombres

Comment: nom = JSON.parse(response)[0]; utilizando esto me aparece los dos nombres que me responde el ajax

Comment: @nosoyGuti no hagas caso a mi anterior comentario, el código debería estar bien como al principio, el `undefined` debe venir de otra parte.

Comment: @nosoyGuti creo que falta contexto. ¿Puedes mostrar el código que procesa la respuesta (PHP u otro en el servidor) o una captura con el objeto desglosado? Es confuso lo de `Array [ {…}, {…} ] ​ 0: Object { nombre: "PERIODO DE PRUEBA" } ​ 1: Object { nombre: "PERIODO EXPERIMENTO" }` por otra parte, el elemento `textoP` es un `th`, si quieres agregar varios `th`, uno por cada nombre, debes hacerlo en un elemento `tr`, que sería el contenedor de cada `th`, pues los `th` son celdas de una fila.

Comment: @nosoyGuti si `response` es un array como el que muestro en el snippet, al final de la pregunta, debería funcionar. Observa que he puesto en la tabla un elemento `tr` con el id `tableHeaders` y que luego hago `append` de los `th`  que se construyen dentro del `for` abriendo  y cerrando la etiqueta `th` en cada caso.

Comment: me ocurre esto y no consigo seguir adelante: var nom
                 $.ajax({
                    url: '',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: '',
                    success: function(response){ 
                        var nom = JSON.parse(response);
for (var p = 0; p <nom.length; p++) {
 fila2 += `<th style=" font-size: 0.9em;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #dddddd;">${nom[p].nombre}`; }
                        $('#textoP').append(fila2)
          } });   fila2 = ' id="textoP" </th>

Comment: actualizacion A. Cedano he conseguido que me meta un nombre en la fila, pero no consigo que me inserte el otro te lo muestro:  success: function(response){ 
                        var nom = JSON.parse(response);
                        for (var p = 0; p <nom.length; p++) {
                        fila2 = `${nom[p].nombre}`;
                        console.log(nom)

                        }

                        $('#textoP').append(fila2)
}    
});     let check = 0
fila2 += '<th id="textoP" style=" font-size: 0.9em;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #dddddd;">'

Comment: Solucionada A. Cedano muchas gracias por tu ayuda.